# Slow shutdown in WSL2

Tags: 22.04, shutdown, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lts

[image: Screenshot of shutdown process]

After `Sending SIGTERM to remaining processes...` it hangs for maybe a minute. This is Ubuntu on WSL2 in a fresh Win11 Pro install.

Is there any way to speed up the shutdown process?